# Running code regardless of observables existing, but waiting for them if they do?

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, observable, angular10

I have the following code:

```js
    array1.foreach(a => {
      if (a === whatever) {
        function1.subscribe();
      }
    });
    array2.foreach(b => {
      if (b === whatever) {
        function2.subscribe();
      }
    });
    function3();
```

How do I make sure that `function3` is always called, but if `function1` and/or `function2` are called, it's only called after the Observables have finished?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't wait for async operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of `Observables` depends on your conditions and then add another one `of(true)` to be sure that if no `Observables` added to the array, `combineLatest` operator works anyway. Your functions `function1()` and `function2()` must return an `Observable`.

```js
const requestsArr: Observable<any>[] = [];

array1.foreach(a => {
 if(a === whatever){
  requestsArr.push( function1() );
 }
});

array2.foreach(b => {
 if(b === whatever){
  requestsArr.push( function2() );
 }
});

requestsArr.push( of(true) );

combineLatest(requestsArr).subscribe( (values: any[]) => {
    ...//do something with values
    function3();
});
```